# asp.net MVC Date Format month(word)/day/year

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, date-format

I've been using **Format("{0:M/d/yyy}")** but it displays

> 1/27/2016 *for example*

Is it possible to display January 27, 2016 using Format() in mvc? or is there existing specific date format of it?

Comment: `MMMM d, yyyy` maybe?

Comment: Sir, good kind this solved my little problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the specifier:

```
MMMM d, yyyy
```